# Subsonic 3 fails to identify Stored Procedure Output Parameter

Tags: stored-procedures, subsonic, subsonic3

Hi using Subsonic 3.0.0.3 it appears there is some issue with Subsonic identifying Stored Procedure paramters as output parameters.

In the StoredProcedures.cs class I find my stored procedure definition but the last parameter is defined incorrectly as a 'AddParameter'.

```
sp.Command.AddParameter("HasPermission",HasPermission,DbType.Boolean);
```

When I sp.Execute() and attempt to read the value of the sp.Command.OutputValues[0] the value is null.

If the definition is edited to be like this;

```
sp.Command.AddOutputParameter("HasPermission", DbType.Boolean);
```

Then the value is returned and is correct value type

I am not sure how I 'fix' this - as everytime I regen the SP class via the 'Run Custom Tool' the parameter definitions require editing. Should I edit a T4 template somehow?

Please advise.

EDIT: I forgot to mention I am using MS SQL 2008 (10.0.2531)

Comment: I think this should be handled, maybe submit a ticket on the issue tracker? http://github.com/subsonic/SubSonic-3.0/issues

It's definitely in the T4 template. It's probably not properly detecting output params to generate the correct code.

Comment: Created issue on Github; http://github.com/subsonic/SubSonic-3.0/issues#issue/118

Answer (score 0):

Was hoping with subsonic 3.0.0.4 this was fixed but sadly no. Fix can be done following this blog entry; http://brianmrush.wordpress.com/2010/01/15/subsonic-and-t4-templates/

Basically add this to SQLServer.ttinclude;

```
p.ParameterDirection = GetParamDirection(row["PARAMETER_MODE"].ToString());
```

And ad this method to SQLServer.ttinclude;

```
string GetParamDirection(string paramMode)
{
    switch (paramMode)
    {
    case "IN":
        return "ParameterDirection.Input";
    case "INOUT":
        return "ParameterDirection.InputOutput";
        case "OUT":
        return "ParameterDirection.Output";
    case "RETURN":
        return "ParameterDirection.ReturnValue";
    default:
        return "ParameterDirection.Input";
    }
}
```

Then in the StoredProcedure.tt file modify line 21 to look like this;

```
sp.Command.AddParameter("<#=par.Name#>",<#=par.CleanName#>,DbType.<#=par.DbType#>);
```